# android: sugar orm library database migration not work

Tags: android, sugarorm

i have db.sql contain book title and writer . base on [these document](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html) i make 1.sql and copy this code on :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "book";
CREATE TABLE "book" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "title" TEXT, "author" TEXT);
INSERT INTO "book" VALUES(1,'First','anyone');
INSERT INTO "book" VALUES(2,'Second','anyone');
```

and change the manifest :

```
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="book.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.app.app.databasetest" />
```

but when app start force close . i change Version 2 and 3 but when start and i want slectall book nothing show :(

Comment: Can you post your logcat